# How to fill attributes with values from input?

Tags: python

How to fill attributes with values from input? I have something like this.

```
class Names(object):

    def __init__(self, name, nickname):

        self.name = name
        self.nickname = nickname
```

And in another class...

```
def userlog():
    name = input("Your name: ")
    nickname = input("Your nickname: ")
```

I need to put values in this attributes and save them to .txt file.

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you rephrase it?
What is exactly your problem - is it getting input from user? passing variables as argument?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def userlog():
    name = input("Your name: ")
    nickname = input("Your nickname: ")
    provided_inputs = Names(name, nickname)
```

For saving it on a text file, you could try a CSV format just as strings. One format could be "name, nickname"

Use the following function for saving the info:

```
def write_to_file(file_path, text_to_write, write_type='wt'):
    with open(file_path, write_type) as f:
        f.write(text_to_write)
        f.close()
```

Once you have that ready, modify your `userlog` function as follows:

```
def userlog():
    .........
    provided_inputs = Names(name, nickname)  # This saves onto Names class 
    write_to_file('/tmp/you_path',
                  '{},{}'.format(name, nickname)  # This saves the strings on a file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains 2 parts:

1. How to create an instance of the class `Names`
2. How to write that instance to text file

To address the first part, after you have the user types in the name and nick name, you can create a new object like this:

```
def userlog():
    name = input("Your name: ")
    nickname = input("Your nickname: ")
    user = Names(name, nickname)
    return user
```

For the second part, you need to open a file for writing, and write it out in any format you like:

```
user = userlog()
with open('output.txt', 'wt') as output_file:
    output_file.write('Name: {}'.format(user.name))
    output_file.write('Nick: {}'.format(user.nickname))
```